# Is it possible to leave my citizenship/passport and still live in the EU?

Tags: citizenship, passport

I am a citizen of a **'[shithole](https://www.theatlantic.com/politics/archive/2019/01/shithole-countries/580054/)'** country and living in an EU country doing my Ph.D.

I am fed up with my country, and so I want to leave my citizenship and passport.

Can I continue to live and freely travel in the EU after leaving my citizenship and passport?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can stateless individuals in the European Union legally reside and work there?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7371/can-stateless-individuals-in-the-european-union-legally-reside-and-work-there)

Comment: The more relevant question would be whether *your country* allows you to renounce your citizenship without having another one.

Comment: I don't think you can become voluntarily stateless.

Comment: @gerrit as a general matter, that is incorrect.  Several countries do not allow it, but we don't know whether OP's country is one of them.

Comment: As an alternative to voluntarily becoming stateless (with all the difficulties that will bring), why not aim to gain EU citizenship *before* renouncing your birth nationality?

Comment: @Traveller, Coz, it will take many more years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have problems without a passport. And even in rare situations where being stateless would be of advantage, that doesn’t apply if you made yourself stateless.

Additionally, you won’t be stateless unless your country allows it.

Don’t do it.